# Issues with Rust/Diesel queries

Tags: sql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm fairly new to Diesel and wanted to add it to a Rocket project.
I followed the tutorials then decided to create tables and queries on my own.

So here is the issue : when I try to do a simple request like `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id = ?` using the query builder, I get compile-time errors that I cannot understand.

Here is the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(i32, std::string::String, std::string::String): FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), Sqlite>` is not satisfied
    --> src/dbal/quote_subject.rs:26:12
     |
26   |     .first(db)
     |      ----- ^^ the trait `FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), Sqlite>` is not implemented for `(i32, std::string::String, std::string::String)`
     |      |
     |      required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromStaticSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T0,) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST0,), __DB>>
               <(T1, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST0), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST0), __DB>>
             and 24 others
note: required for `QuoteSubject` to implement `diesel::Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), Sqlite>`
    --> src/models.rs:5:24
     |
5    | #[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
     |                        ^^^^^^^^^
6    | #[diesel(table_name = quote_subject)]
7    | pub struct QuoteSubject {
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
     = note: required for `QuoteSubject` to implement `FromSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text), Sqlite>`
     = note: required for `(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text)` to implement `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<QuoteSubject, Sqlite>`
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<schema::quote_subject::table>, diesel::query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause<FromClause<schema::quote_subject::table>>, diesel::query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, diesel::query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<expression::grouped::Grouped<expression::operators::Eq<schema::quote_subject::columns::id, _>>>, diesel::query_builder::order_clause::NoOrderClause, diesel::query_builder::limit_offset_clause::LimitOffsetClause<diesel::query_builder::limit_clause::LimitClause<expression::bound::Bound<BigInt, i64>>, diesel::query_builder::offset_clause::NoOffsetClause>>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, diesel::SqliteConnection, QuoteSubject>`
note: required by a bound in `first`
    --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.0.2/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1736:22
     |
1736 |         Limit<Self>: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `first`
     = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Queryable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `le-saviez-vous` due to previous error
```

FYI, I'm using SQLite for this project.

Here is my code :

```rust
/// src/dbal/quote_subject.rs

use crate::schema::quote_subject::dsl::*;
use crate::models::QuoteSubject;
use diesel::{SqliteConnection, QueryDsl, RunQueryDsl};
use crate::helpers::database;

use diesel::prelude::*;

/// this function aims to get one QuoteSubject object from table `quote_subject` with it's Id.
pub fn find(object_id: i64) -> QuoteSubject {
    let db: &mut SqliteConnection = &mut get_connection();

    quote_subject
    .filter(id.eq(object_id.into()))
    .first(db)
    .unwrap()
}
```

```rust
/// src/models.rs

use diesel::prelude::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use crate::schema::*;

#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[diesel(table_name = quote_subject)]
pub struct QuoteSubject {
    pub id: i32,
    pub quote_singular: String,
    pub quote_plural: String
}

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct QuoteVerb {
    pub id: i32,
    pub quote_singular: String,
    pub quote_plural: String
}

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct QuoteDescription {
    pub id: i32,
    pub quote_singular: String,
    pub quote_plural: String
}
```

```rust
/// src/schema.rs

diesel::table! {
    quote_description (id) {
        id -> Nullable<Integer>,
        quote_singular -> Text,
        quote_plural -> Text,
    }
}
```

```sql
-- the migration used to create the table inside the SQLite database
CREATE TABLE "quote_subject" (
    id             INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    quote_singular VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    quote_plural   VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Tried various searches and some code replacement following git issues but could not make it to work.

Comment: This could simply be that you don't have appropriate modules included, can you please share the full list of model.rs ; or do you have a gist?

Comment: I updated the original message with the full model.rs file, and you can find the project in it's last -bugged- version here : https://github.com/AdrienGras/le-saviez-vous-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll simplify the error message:

```
the trait bound `(i32, String, String): FromStaticSqlRow<(Nullable<Integer>, Text, Text), Sqlite>` is not satisfied
```

Can you spot it now? This will try to construct an `i32` from a `Nullable<Integer>` but this is not possible because the value could be `NULL`.

Now, its not going to be `NULL` because you have `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` which [implies](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) `NOT NULL`, but the `schema.rs` still has the `id` column marked as `Nullable`.

Change your schema to declare `id -> Integer` instead.

Comment: You're the best ! it works ! I patched some other errors and now data are correctly imported from database.

Comment: >  but the schema.rs still has the id column marked as Nullable.

That's because `diesel print-schema` uses `PRAGMA table_info('…')` internally and that states that these columns are nullable without an explicit `NOT NULL` constraint.